# Cannot upload an Image to mySQL database (JSON/Volley/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, blob, android-volley

Please help a person out.. I'm close I can feel it. Forgive me if duplicate but not seeing any answers that work.

I have created a mySQL database and already connected using php/android/volley and started updating data through the application. So I know that connection and adding data bit works.

However I now need to add an image to the database. And it is not happening. A  new row does not get added to the database at all (it did before I added blob column)

I have been following a mixture of two tutorials, while using local WAMP myphpsql at the moment

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/.  (Looking at php code)

**I think my problem lies in the php side.**

**SQL TABLE STRUCTURE**
[image]

**PHP: DB_Functions_FamilyMembers.php**

```
 public function storeFamilyMember($name, $account_id, $bio, $user_pic) {

  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO family_member(name, account_id, bio, user_pic) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $account_id, $bio,  $user_pic);

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();


    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM family_member WHERE account_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $family_member = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $family_member;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**PHP: familymembers.php**

```
<?php 

require_once 'include/DB_Functions_FamilyMembers.php';
$db = new DB_Functions_FamilyMembers();
// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

//if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['account_id'], $_POST['bio']), $POST['user_pic']) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $account_id = $_POST['account_id'];
    $bio = $_POST['bio'];
    $user_pic = $_POST['user_pic'];

        $family_member = $db->storeFamilyMember($name, $account_id, $bio, $user_pic);

    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["family_member"]["name"] = $family_member["name"];
    $response["family_member"]["account_id"] = $family_member["account_id"];
    $response["family_member"]["bio"] = $family_member["bio"];
    $response["family_member"]["user_pic"] = $family_member["user_pic"];
    echo json_encode($response);

    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";

       echo json_encode($response);

    }
?>
```

**ANDROID: FamilyMemberFragmentAdd.java - Volley Map**

```
 @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("account_id", id);
                params.put("bio", bio);
                params.put("user_pic", uploadImage );
                return params;
            }
```

**ANDROID: FamilyMemberFragmentAdd.java - METHOD: getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap)**

```
  public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){

     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

I do think it lies within the PHP/SQL setup, because all other fields were updated fine before I tried to upload blob.

Thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-optimization-tips.html

With Web servers, store images and other binary assets as files, with the path name stored in the database rather than the file itself. Most Web servers are better at caching files than database contents, so using files is generally faster. (Although you must handle backups and storage issues yourself in this case.)

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. So with my application, as the user is either using the camera, or picking a photo from the gallery, I take it that I will need to somehow upload that photo to the server (which is local for me).  And then I assume that I will need to use php file to load that path which then will be applied to the mySQL coloumn. Is this the correct approach?  Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, that is correct, save only the file path. So your server side code is more or less similar to the file upload sample code in the php docs.

Comment: Is it downvoted because of duplicate? Or Question Structure, If duplicate I remove the question, if Structure of question I will restructure it.

Comment: Hi! I followed your advice and it worked.  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction, I was definately missing that line of thinking to get it to work.  (Bit rushed, so logic is missing)

Comment: Don't know if it's still relevant,  but you shouldn't use a String to send image/file data, the correct way is a MultipartRequest, especially if you're using Volley, since in that case you need to extend it yourself. My guess is the info isn't coming in correctly, might be the whole problem, might be part of it, and @e4c5 is very right, store the local path/url into the db, not the blob itself.

Comment: Hi guys, it did work out I did store the path and url in to the database and it works fabulously and I used Picasso (which is easy) to load the image back into the app.  If anyone wants to post an Answer and I will confirm followed by the amendments i did to the above code.  Thanks again for the input

Comment: honors go to @e4c5 :)

Answer (score 1):

I have one sample code where I am uploading images and storing in the database you can check that.

```
$mysql= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$response = array(); // response to client




    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"]) && @$_POST["user_name"]){
        $tmp_file = $_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"]; //get file from client
        $img_name = $_FILES["user_image"]["name"];
        $upload_dir = "./image/".$img_name;

        $sql = " INSERT INTO user (user_name,user_profile) VALUES ('{$_POST['user_name']}', '{$img_name}')";
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir) && $mysql->query($sql)){
            $response["MESSAGE"] = "UPLOAD SUCCED";
            $response["STATUS"] =200;
        }
        else{
            $response["MESSAGE"] = "UPLOAD FAILED";
            $response["STATUS"] = 404;
        }
    }else{

        $response["MESSAGE"] = "INVALID REQUEST";
        $response["STATUS"] =400;
    }

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```